# How do I get the last bonus points in Gun Mettle

Tags: team-fortress-2

I get up to 28 or 29 bonus points on my contract, but can never seem to get the last point or two.  Is there something specific that you have to do or something special you need to do to finish the bonus points?

Comment: Only what is required of the 'advanced' tasks. So for example, the Soldier one 'kill while in the air after rocket jumping' - regular kills/captures won't do it.

Answer (score 4):

In the *Gun Mettle* update, contracts are fulfilled by reaching the points cap through listed objectives. There are 'regular' objectives, normally earning you a point or two (or even three!) every time they are performed, and then there are objectives tagged with **(Advanced)**. These **Advanced** objectives, in most cases, will get you about 10 points. Once the contract has been fulfilled, a new counter will appear that requires you gain 30 points to collect said points as a bonus for your badge. However, this new counter will only count how many times you complete one of the **Advanced** objectives - for example, if you need 30 points to collect your Snowplow contract and you get 10 points per round won (assuming winning is your only **Advanced** contract), you will need to win 3 times to collect the bonus.

Comment: "However, this new counter will only count how many times you completed the Advanced objectives" Actually... only one of the Advanced objectives works during this, usually the second one.

Comment: Are you sure? I swear I've completed contracts for bonus points by completing both of the advanced objectives.

Comment: I've completed 7 contracts.  All of them used just one of the Advanced objectives for bonus points.  Always the more annoying of the two, such as "Win a round" for the map-based contracts or "Uber a Heavy to take down a sentry" for Medic.

Comment: Huh, I've been doing every contract since the beginning across 3 accounts, I can't believe I never noticed it! I'll edit the post to include that now.

Comment: I had a Medic contract with two advanced objectives, and for the bonus it let me do either. So either there's a hidden value somewhere or Valve is changing things without letting anyone know.

Comment: @Powerlord - I, like Toomai, also had a contract that allowed me to do either Advanced objective for the bonus points section